# Unable to get the adapter view item with mvxlistview

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an mvxlistview that is populated. I have a swipe gesture also implemented, the idea being sweep left on an item performs action 1 and sweep right does something else.

I'm using PointToPosition from the move event to get the item under the swipe. While it works for the first item (the PointToPosition method gives a value of 1 which from what I can see is fine as you subtract 1 from that value for the true position), the second item gives a value of -1 (the value when there is nothing under the items

The code I'm using is this

```
// Activity - the IOnTouchListener and IOnItemSelectedListener and IOnLongClickListeners can be ignored

public class WishList : MvxActivity,View.IOnTouchListener, AdapterView.IOnItemSelectedListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
{
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    private int REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE;
    private int REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH;
    private int REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.WishListView);

        var d = new ColorDrawable(Color.White);
        ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(d);

        var dm = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = (int)(120f * (float)dm.DensityDpi / (160f + .5));
        REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = (int)(250f * (float)dm.DensityDpi / (160f + .5));
        REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = (int)(200f * (float)dm.DensityDpi / (160f + .5));

        var lv = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector(lv, REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE, REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH, REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY));
        lv.Focusable = true;
        /*lv.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        lv.ItemLongClick += HandleLongClick;*/
    }

    void HandleDrag(object sender, View.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as MvxListItemView;
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    void HandleLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListView;
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v);
        return true;
    }

    public void OnItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pos = {0}", position);
        //return true;
    }

    public void OnNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
    {
        //return true;
    }

    public bool OnLongClick(View v)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v);
        return true;
    }



    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e))
        {
            if (MyGestureDetector.currentGestureDetected == "LTR")
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Share wishlist item", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            if (MyGestureDetector.currentGestureDetected == "RTL")
            {
                var _vm = ((WishListViewModel)ViewModel);
                var items = _vm.WishListItems;
                Console.WriteLine("hi");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

// MyGestureDetector.cs

public class MyGestureDetector : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    MvxListView listView;
    int REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE;
    int REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH;
    int REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;
    Context context;
    public static string currentGestureDetected;

    public MyGestureDetector(MvxListView lv, int minDist, int maxPath, int velo)
    {
        listView = lv;
        context = lv.Context;
        REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = maxPath;
        REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = minDist;
        REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = velo;
    }

    public override bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        var pos = listView.PointToPosition((int)e.GetX(), (int)e.GetY());
        currentGestureDetected = string.Format("Item clicked = {0}", pos);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(e1.GetY() - e2.GetY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;
        if (e1.GetX() - e2.GetX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.Abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
            RightToLeftFling((int)e2.GetX(), (int)e2.GetY());
        else
        {
            if (e2.GetX() - e1.GetX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.Abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
                LeftToRightFling((int)e2.GetX(), (int)e2.GetY());
        }
        return true;
    }

    void RightToLeftFling(int x, int y)
    {
        currentGestureDetected = "RTL";
        var posn = listView.PointToPosition(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("position = {0}", posn);
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Right to left fling", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }

    void LeftToRightFling(int x, int y)
    {
        currentGestureDetected = "LTR";
        var posn = listView.PointToPosition(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("position = {0}", posn);
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Left to right fling", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}

 // Resource.Layout.WishListView

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
orientation="vertical">
<!--Header-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/payar_green"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wishlist"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/Header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Visible ItemsDontExist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your wishlist is currently empty!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource WishListItems; ItemClick ShowProductCommand; Visible ItemsExist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/_wishlistitemtest"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

// Resource.Layout._wishlistitemtest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">
<RelativeLayout
    local:MvxBind="Visible IsTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Text Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="store name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    local:MvxBind="Visible IsItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Text Name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="product name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Text FormattedTotalPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="price"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
<!--<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
        <Switch
            local:MvxBind="Checked RemoveCommand"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="Keep"
            android:textOff="Remove"
            android:checked="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug in mvvmcross or a problem with Xamarin.Android or something else.

Comment: Please put the code here and not in an offsite resource...

Comment: Will do. The code is not that short though